# solr request handler doesn't consider default parameter

Tags: parameters, solr, request, default

When i add somme default parameter to solr request handler, solr doesn't consider it.

My request handler is like this :

```
  <requestHandler name="default" class="solr.SearchHandler" lazy="true" default="true">  
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">dismax</str>
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <str name="bf">
        docRank
    </str>
  <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
  <str name="hl.usePhraseHighLighter">true</str>
  <str name="hl.highlightMultiTerm">true</str>
  <str name="hl.mergeContiguous">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
    <str>highlight</str>
    <str>spellcheck</str>
 </arr>
```

However, when i request solr with "defType=dismax&bf=docRank", it works.

Solr use this handler because if i remove it, solr throw exception.

Thanks for help.

Comment: could you please add an example of your query? If your query used an syntax from the lucene default search handler, solr will use the lucene default search handler, even if you set this dismax configuration as default="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found why it doesn't work. The syntax of the two handler is different (default and dismax).

Thanks for your help.